When plotting a trend line in a Kendo UI line chart within an MVC app dates not plotted correctly it's in GMT which required in UTC

This function converts the date from a string format to a JavaScript Date object in UTC. The current implementation creates a new Date object using the toISOString method, which is not necessary. Instead, you should return the dateObj directly.

/****************************************************************/
function toDate(value) {
    var dateRegExp = /^\/Date\((.*?)\)\/$/;
    var date = dateRegExp.exec(value);
    var timestamp = parseInt(date[1], 10);            
    var dateObj = new Date(timestamp);
    console.log("GMT" + dateObj.toISOString());
    return new Date(dateObj.toISOString()); // Ensures date is in UTC
}

/**************************************************************************************/

DataSource Configuration: Make sure the parse function in your data source configurations properly converts the date.

            var heatExchangerSurveyCalculationsDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                 transport: {
                     read: {
                         url: function () {
                             return '@Url.Action("GetHeatExchangerSurveyCalculations", "Dashboard")';
                         },
                         dataType: "json",
                         cache: false,                         
                         type: "POST"
                     },
                     parameterMap: dataSourceParameterMap
                 },
                 requestStart: function () {
                     heatExchangerSurveyCalculationsLoading = true;
                     requestStart();
                 },
                 requestEnd: function () {
                     heatExchangerSurveyCalculationsLoading = false;
                     onRequestEnd();
                 },
                group: {
                    field: "Name"
                },
                 schema: {
                     parse: function (response) {
                         $.each(response, function (i, v) {
                             v.TimeStamp = toDate(v.TimeStamp);
                         });

                         return response;
                     }
                },
                 error: function(e) {
                     onError("#skinTempChart");
                     onError("#WaterVelocityChart");
                     onError("#HeatFluxChart");
                     onError("#WaterFlowDataChart");
                     onError("#UCoefficientChart");
                 }
             });

             var approachTemperatureDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                 transport: {
                     read: {
                         url: function () {
                             return '@Url.Action("GetApproachTempChartData", "Dashboard")';
                         },
                         dataType: "json",
                         cache: false,
                         sort: { field: "year", dir: "asc" },
                         type: "POST"
                     },
                     parameterMap: dataSourceParameterMap
                 },
                 sort: { field: "year", dir: "asc" },
                 requestStart: function () {
                     approachTempChartDataLoading = true;
                     requestStart();
                 },
                 requestEnd: function () {
                     approachTempChartDataLoading = false;
                     onRequestEnd();
                 },
                 group: {
                     field: "EquipmentDescription"
                 },
                 schema: {
                     parse: function (response) {
                         $.each(response, function (i, v) {
                             v.TimeStamp = toDate(v.TimeStamp);
                         });

                         return response;
                     }
                 },
                 error: function(e) {
                     onError('#ApproachTempChart');
                 }
             });

/********************************************************************************************/The chart is not plotted correctly using the web API. It binds dates with values on the tooltip along the x-axis, which shows months and the year.

 function onContentLoad(e) {
     var skinTempChart = $("#skinTempChart").kendoChart({
         title: {
             text: "Skin Temp",
             visible: false
         },
         legend: {
             position: "top"
         },
         dataBound: function (e) {
             setColors("#skinTempChart");
             onNoData(e, "#skinTempChart");
         },
         dataSource: heatExchangerSurveyCalculationsDataSource,
         sortable: true,
         autoBind: false,
         series: [
             {
                 type: "line",
                 categoryField: "TimeStamp",
                 field: "SkinTemp",
                 name: "#= group.value #",
                 axis: "temp",
                 tooltip: {
                     visible: true,
                     template: "${ kendo.toString(value, 'n0')}" + "</br>" + " ${ kendo.toString(new Date(category), 'MM/d/yyyy') }"
                 }
             }
         ],
         categoryAxis: [{
             baseUnit: "weeks",
             baseUnitStep: 4,  // Display labels every 4 weeks
             labels: {
                 step: 4,
                 template: '#= kendo.toString((value), "MMM yy" ) #',
                 dateFormats: {
                     months: "MMM yy"
                 },
                 visible: true
             }
         }],
         valueAxis: [
             {
                 name: "temp",
                 autoScale: true,
                 min: 0,
                 plotBands: [
                     {
                         color: "#ff0",
                         opacity: 0.2
                     },
                     {
                         color: "#ff0000",
                         opacity: 0.2
                     }
                 ]

             }
         ],
         tooltip: { visible: true }
     }).data('kendoChart');
}

Data Parsing: Ensure dates are correctly parsed and converted to UTC in the parse function of the data source.

Chart Configuration: Make sure the chart's category axis and tooltips are configured to correctly interpret and display the dates.


Date comes in GMT but it needs in UTC

enter image description here
The date passed to the chart is GMT2024-05-02T06:30:00.000Z, but it is not displaying correctly on the charts.
Correct Date Conversion: Simplify the toDate function to ensure it directly returns the Date object in UTC.

Parsing Dates in DataSource: Ensure dates are correctly parsed and converted to Date objects in the schema.parse function.

Chart Configuration: Ensure the chart is configured to correctly display dates on the x-axis with proper formatting.


By implementing these changes, you should be able to ensure that dates are displayed correctly on the charts. If you still encounter issues, double-check the date format and time zone settings in your data source and chart configurations.
